# flutter arrow on Column children

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

## hi guys! I'm facing this issue with Column Widget,

when I debug my app and open the page it pauses the debug process and gives me this arrow on text Widget I tried to write Fixed "String" value and still giving me this arrow in the same place 
[the arrow on Text widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLQ3e.png)

and I removed the entire widget but the arrow moved to the next widget witch is Row widget

[when I removed the widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZC6A.png)

I hope you can help me

- 1-    no null values
- 2- no overlays

#### the code

```
class ProductScreenBody extends StatelessWidget {
  final String productReturn;
  final int price;
  final int delivery;
  final String deliveryTime;
  final String name;
  final String describtion;
  final String image;
  final String categoryPath;
  final String warranty;
  ProductScreenBody(
      {Key? key,
      required this.warranty,
      required this.price,
      required this.productReturn,
      required this.delivery,
      required this.deliveryTime,
      required this.name,
      required this.image,
      required this.categoryPath,
      required this.describtion})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ScreenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final ScreenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      height: ScreenHeight,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: ScreenWidth,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  describtion,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Text(categoryPath,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    ProductRating(),
                    Text(
                      "(5/5)",
                    ),
                    Text(" Ordered (" + 122.toString() + ") times.",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it's related to VS Code, what happens when you click on that arrow?

Comment: nothing happens I think it just shows me that something went wrong but I can't find it or a bug on VS Code I don't know, I'll try with Android Studio and show you then, thanks for the point :)

Comment: I'm using Android Studio and think that it's a feature of VS Code, because in Android Studio there is no arrows like that. You're welcome.

Comment: Yah like you said, it worked on Android Studio and thanks again bro

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, that's a step arrow, see the red dot on the line above the arrow? that's a breakpoint, you added it by clicking on the place where the breakpoint now is,

A breakpoint is a debugging tool to stop execution of a program halfway through said program, in your case, you told vscode you wanted to stop execution on line 169, but line 169 only has a parenthesis, which means there is nothing to execute on that line, so instead, execution stops on the next line, which is your Text widget's line.

The arrow signifies the current point of your program, as I said, the breakpoint tells the program to stop, so the program stops at the Text widget's line and vscode shows you the arrow so you know the program stopped.

To remove the arrow, you can either remove the breakpoint (by clicking the red dot again) and execute the program again (or hot-reload or full-restart the program), or you can press the continue button on your debugging board.

Your debugging board is a bunch of buttons that appear while you are debugging, if the arrow is visible, your debugging board should look like this:

[image: debugging board]

You should be able to see it on the top right corner of vscode while debugging (it isn't visible while the program isn't running)

The "play" button will continue execution until you reach another breakpoint, you can also use the "next line button" (the button directly to the right of the "play" button) to execute the line with the arrow on it, conversely moving the arrow into the next executable line.

Android studio also has this feature and it works the same way, although the visuals might be different.

Comment: Okaaay Okaaay now I got it, now that's makes sense, I thought breakpoint was used to mark the area to work on, thanks Mr @h8miss, you saved my educational journey!

Comment: Happy to help ^^